# SQL SERVER changing security contex inside of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Inside of some stored procedure I have to change security context to more powerful login.
I tried something like this:

```
USE ProjectsDB
EXECUTE AS login = 'sa'

--SOME OPERATIONS

REVERT;
```

but I get the following error message:

```
Msg 15406, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Cannot execute as the server principal because the principal "sa" does not exist,
this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.
```

The 'sa' login exist with all needed permissions.
What may be the problem?

Ilan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the "IMPERSONATE" permission to do this. Check out the `GRANT IMPERSONATE` statement.

Besides that I believe the best way to do this (instead of bumping up the permission level to SA) in sql server is:

- Create a certificate
- Sign the stored procedure with the certificate
- Remove the private key from the certificate
- Create a user from the certificate
- Grant the required rights to the user

Optional if you need "Server wide rights":

- Export the certificate to disk
- Import the certificate in the master database
- Create a login from the certificate
- Grant the appropriate rights to the login

More optional if you need "cross database rights"

- import the certificate in the database where you want to grant permissions
- create a user from the certificate.
- grant the correct rights to the user

SQL Server will chain all the users/login permissions together through the certificates and when you execute the signed procedure it will use the permissions of the users linked to the certificate.

Comment: @Flip Wow!!!!!!!!!!!! Could you recommend some book (e-book) that covers all these? :)

Comment: Erland Sommarskog has the best info (as usual) http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html